Serialization and Deserilization C# Expressions with Remote.Linq
Can anyone help me and share an example of how I can serialize and deserialize C# Expressions with Remote.Linq and System.Text.Json? I did not find any working examples.
Expression<Func<int, bool>> expression = x => x > 5;

var remoteExpression = expression.ToRemoteLinqExpression();

???


Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?.

Based on this I'm able to serialize via JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions().ConfigureRemoteLinq(); string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(remoteExpression, serializerOptions);. But I haven't figured out how to deserialize that.

@StriplingWarrior Thanks for your hint I found the answer. :)

I found the answer
Expression<Func<int, int>> expr = x => x + 1;
var remoteExpression = expr.ToRemoteLinqExpression();

var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions().ConfigureRemoteLinq();
var serializedExpr = JsonSerializer.Serialize(remoteExpression, serializerOptions);

var deserializedExpr =  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Remote.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression>(serializedExpr, serializerOptions);
var originalExpr = deserializedExpr?.ToLinqExpression();

var result = originalExpr?.Compile().DynamicInvoke(1); // 2

